# How to get vector from matrix in Maxima

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, maxima

I want to multiply matrix M to vector V. Should be a vector.
I write

```
M:matrix([a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,r]);
V:[w,k,t];
res:M.V;
```

I get the column-matrix. 
I want to get list `[a*w+c*t+b*k,d*w+f*t+e*k,g*w+r*t+h*k]`. 
OK. I have to write `res:[res[1][1],res[2][1],res[3][1]];`
How to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

```
transpose(res)[1];

-> [a*w+c*t+b*k,d*w+f*t+e*k,g*w+r*t+h*k]
```

Answer (score 1):

This function returns the i-th column of a matrix
similar to Matlabs M(:,i)

```
col(M,i) := 
    block(
        return(transpose(transpose(M)[i])) 
    )$
```

This function returns the i-th row of a matrix similar to Matlabs M(i,:)

```
row(M,i) := 
    block(
        return(transpose(transpose(M[i])))
    )$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this, for completeness, in case anyone else has the same question.

First, I believe `V`, as defined in the OP, is actually a `list` and not a `vector`, by Maxima's definitions; however, the approach is the same, in either case:

```
M:matrix([a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,r]);
V:[w,k,t];                /* V is a list */
v1:transpose([w,k,t]);    /* v1 is a column vector */
v2:matrix([w],[k],[t]);   /* v2 is a column vector */
```

**In all cases, use `args`**:

```
output1:args(M.V);   /* returns a list of lists */
output2:args(M.v1);  /* returns a row vector */
output3:args(M.v2);  /* returns a row vector */
```

will return objects that *look* the same, but don't have exactly the same behaviour. For example:

```
output1[1,1];   /* will return an error, because `output1` is a list, not a matrix */
output1[1][1];  /* will return the first (only) entry of the first list */

output2[1,1];  /* returns the 1-1 element of the vector `output2` */
output2[1][1]; /* isn't defined, because `output2` is a vector, not a list */
```

(and similarly for output3).